# Google Now Card Image

Tags: image, email

I'm working on setting up a hotel reservation Google Now Card for an email confirmation, but I can't get a different image to show.

Right now it just shows a default "San Francisco" image. I'm setting an image URL in the JSON markup, but it does nothing.

Am I missing something or is this even possible?

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context" : "http://schema.org",
  "@type" : "LodgingReservation",
  "reservationNumber" : "10019",
  "reservationFor" : {
    "@type" : "LodgingBusiness",
    "name" : "San Francisco Inn",
    "image" : "http://usa.sae.edu/assets/Campuses/San-Francsico/2015/San_Francisco_city_view.jpg",
    "address" : {
      "@type" : "PostalAddress",
      "streetAddress" : "123 South Van Ness Avenue",
      "addressLocality" : "San Francisco",
      "addressRegion" : "CA",
      "postalCode" : "94110"
    }
  },
  "underName" : {
    "@type" : "Person",
    "name" : "John Smith"
  },
  "price" : "$215.00",
  "checkinDate" : "2016-01-15",
  "checkoutDate" : "2016-01-20",
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain but a few things to check to help things, you have a trailing comma:

"checkoutDate" : "2016-01-20"**,**

I'd also try serving your image over https, much of Google's websites are now https only, normally Google would proxy images in e-mails, however for schema.org markup it might expect https.

Also at the time of writing the LodgingReservation section on the Google documentation says it's prone to change so it's possible something is amiss Google's end.